# Who was the dock worker in Scandinavia who sold Simon the crown?

Tags: adventure-time

According to [Who was the Ice King?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17835/who-was-the-ice-king) the third tape reveals that a long time ago (possibly prior to the Mushroom War), the Ice King was a human named Simon Petrikov, who had a fiancée named Betty.

He was an antiquarian, who

> purchased a strange crown from a dock worker in Scandinavia.

He took the crown home to show Betty. When he put the crown on his head for a laugh, he started to see visions and hallucinations. He fought with them and shouted at them before realizing it was the crown sending the visions into his head.

Who was the dock worker who sold him the crown?

Comment: Sadly, even after the show "finale", I don't think this question has ever got an answer. It is worth noticing that Simon is also the one who found the Enchiridion, and the book is indeed tied to the crown in a way. Still, while the crown does share some similarities with the One Ring from "The Lord Of The Rings", I don't think there is enough ground to claim it was actually trying to reunite with the Enchiridion.